# Append a button when user check the check box and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is an input field. which returned from an ajax response, and then appended to another div.
Now I want when on any checkbox a user clicks a button with some data will be appended to a specific div.

```
<input name="new" onclick="showButton()" value=1 type="checkbox" id="switchButton" data-id="' + order.id + '"  data-toggle="toggle">
```

This is the div where i want to append the button.

```
<div id="setBgColor" class="px-1 py-1 shadow"
style="height: 600px;width: 320px;position: relative;border: solid black 15px;
border-radius: 24px; background-color: #7ecff4;margin-top: -70px;">
```

first i tried the custom function but it doesnt work properly.

```
function showButton() {
    $('#setBgColor').html('<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary"> </button></div>');
}
```

Then I tried this jquery code but it also does nothing.

```
$('#switchButton').on('click').each(function(){
        $('#setBgColor').html('<div><button type="button" ckass="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary"> </button></div>');
    });
```

[image: here is the picture what actually i want]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220035/discussion-on-question-by-waheed-sindhani-append-a-button-when-user-check-the-ch).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define event using jquery. Replace onclick with onchange on input tag

Since we are using checkbox, we need to use onchange event

Can you try

```
<input name="new" onchange="showButton()" value=1 type="checkbox" id="switchButton" data-id="' + order.id + '"  data-toggle="toggle">
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - for simple typos such as this we generally make a comment (see existing comments) and then vote close as a typo (after waiting for feedback from OP to see if it was a typo or as mis-copy into the question).   When you have enough rep, you can also vote close

Comment: Hi. I tried commenting but it seems like i must have 50 reputation to comment. Anyway, thanks for guiding. Will keep in mind.

Comment: You might find this of interest https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @PaulGeorge it is not working for me. I don't know what is causing this problem.

Comment: @WaheedSindhani I have updated my answer. Try using onchange event

Comment: should i put it inside document.ready function or outside of it.??

Comment: You don't need to add it at all. When you append
<input name="new" onclick="showButton()" value=1 type="checkbox" id="switchButton" data-id="' + order.id + '"  data-toggle="toggle">

chnage onclick="showButton()" to onchange="showButton()"

You can define the function showButton as you did first

Comment: Ok when a try  
`$("body").on('change','#switchButton', function(){
  alert('someting');
})`
it works fine.

Comment: but it doesn't add the button to the DOM.

Comment: codepen: https://codepen.io/paul_george/pen/LYNZXKQ

Comment: @PaulGeorge it doesnt hide when you uncheck it
but in my code none of this work i can share my code with you.

Comment: I have updated the codepen. We can pass 'this' as argument in showButton function. 'this' will be the element that triggered the function. In this case the showButton. You can check the checked property to check whether it is checked or not and execute action. Please share the code for better understanding